# Unable to upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04. Package libgd3 not found

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

I tried to upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 using both software updater and 'do-release-upgrade' command. I am getting below error message. My internet connection is working fine. How can i correctly upgrade to 18.04 release.

```
Could not download the upgrades 

The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or 
installation media and try again. All files downloaded so far have 
been kept. 

Failed to fetch 
http://ubuhttps://askubuntu.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2faskubuntu.com%2fquestions%2f1028787%2fuse-old-ppa-if-new-ppa-is-not-available-for-new-ubuntu-versionntu.mirrors.tds.net/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgd2/libgd3_2.2.5-4ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb 
404 Not Found
```

Comment: Did you ping your network to see if they are any packet losses?

Comment: The `http://ubuhttps://askubuntu.com/` in your error message is invalid, and looks wrong.  I tried in a browser and got a 404 too - so I'd `grep` your sources for that string and remove..  Your heading also mentions a package, but the errors don't mention it.